Apple TV 4K with blinking white light of death: is it just an expensive paperweight/e-waste now?
This weekend my Apple TV 4K (1st gen) started erratically responding to remote commands, and then a very small circular progress indicator in the middle of the screen. I waited for a long time, then removed the power and connected again, and this time it exhibited the dreaded blinking white light of death. The TV it's connected to just says "No signal". I tried removing the power for long periods of time and connecting again, still the blinking white light.
I was surprised to learn that the 4K model lost the USB cable that would allow me to connect it to a computer and try to restore it. I called Apple, and since it's out of warranty, they said I have to pay a $149 repair fee (actually more in my country, but either way it makes to sense to pay this to get an older-generation one when the price for the latest one is the same).
Is there really nothing else that can be done? Perhaps a hidden USB connector inside the Apple TV if I were to open it up? Maybe a magic sequence of buttons on the remote, a hidden button or touch surface that triggers a DFU mode/restore operation? Or is it really a $149 paperweight/e-waste now? I just can't believe a $149 device is completely disposable like this.

At the very least, you can hand it back to an Apple Store for recycling. The history of electronics is all about integration and consolidation. We have devices that are largely one component, which can't be repaired unless you've got factory equipment.
